# Is there an upload queue feature for ng-file-upload?

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

Would it be possible using this library? I've used this one for uploading a single file or a batch of files but it only creates a single http request, just like the samples in its github page. What I'm looking for is have an upload queue for the user's upload files so that he/she can still select another file for upload while previous file is still in uploading.

Comment: No sure about ng-file-upload, but [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) provides such functionality.

Comment: I've looking into that right now but the app that I'll be enhancing is already using ng-file-upload library. Was hoping if there's a way to have this feature.

Comment: You can just have an array (queue) in your javascript code that hold all the files and once a new file is selected start uploading it and push it to the array. Or you could achieve this by adding `ngf-keep` directive which will keep adding the new files to the model while holding the previous ones.

Comment: @danial Thanks for the suggestion! I overlooked that step during the $watch event. Can you make your comment an answer so we can close this one? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have an array (queue) in your javascript code that holds all the files and once a new file is selected start uploading it and push it to the array.

Alternatively you could achieve this by adding `ngf-keep="true"` directive which will keep adding the new files to the model while holding the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

with ng-file-upload you can do multiple file select dialog for async file uploads. It then gives the upload progress of all files during the concurrent file uploads.

e.g. file 1 - 50%
file 2 - 75%

I can vouch for this because Ive done it.

See usages ...

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage

can't see any reason why u could not allow the user to select another file whilst the files were uploading.
Just click the upload button again!

Comment: actually we had another page I made that requires the user to upload only one file so that was why I placed a jquery blockUI during upload trigger. The current problem was that whenever user selects a file for upload, the model also refreshed.